# get Touch point in Arc drawn by CGContext

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cgcontext

I have drawn so many arc using below code:

```
CGContextAddArc(context,
                        e.x,
                        e.y,
                        Distance/2,
                        M_PI+angle1,
                        angle1,
                        aClock); 
        CGContextStrokePath(context)
```

Now I want that when I touch any arch I want to detect that which arc has been touched

How can I do that?

Comment: use the old methods for touch (touchbegan, touchmoved, toucheended) to detect where in the screen the touch happened then look for what is near.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

1.add your arc to a path,

```
_path = CGPathCreateMutable();
CGPathAddArc(_path, NULL, e.x, e.y, Distance/2, M_PI + angle1, angle1, aClock);
CGContextAddPath(context, _path);
CGContextStrokePath(context);
```

2.rewrite touchesBegan:withEvent:

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    NSSet *allTouches = [event allTouches];
    UITouch *touch = [allTouches anyObject];
    CGPoint point = [touch locationInView:[touch view]];

    if (CGPathContainsPoint(_path, NULL, point, NO)) {
        NSLog(@"point:(%f, %f), Touch arc.", point.x, point.y);
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"point:(%f, %f), Touch other.", point.x, point.y);
    }
}
```

You'll see the "Touch arc." log when touch arc.